# How do I get a snippet to insert a character only if the user typed something?

Tags: visual-studio-code, transform, code-snippets, tabstop

I have this snippet.

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id, DB_ID(${20:})) + '.' + name,
       *
FROM ${20/$/./}sys.all_objects o
WHERE name LIKE '%${10:hadr}%'
ORDER BY o.name;
```

And this is how it works:

[image: gif of usage of snippet]

When the user types something in the function `DB_ID()`, I hope the content the user typed appears before `sys.all_objects` AND append an additional `.`. It already works like this as it shown in the above gif. However, I also hope if the user types nothing in the function `DB_ID()`, don't add `.` before `sys.all_objects`. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have snippet code already, you should show what you have.

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title, maybe something like, "How do I get a snippet to insert a character only if the user typed something?" Check out [ask] for tips on how to write a good title.

Comment: It'd help to make a [mre]. You can copy the one from my answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehind to assert that there's something in that field: `(?<=.)$`. For a minimal example, let's say this is the original snippet:

```
foo($1); ${1/$/./}bar()
```

Change it to:

```
foo($1); ${1/(?<=.)$/./}bar()
```

If I type something, e.g. `x`, then press Tab, I get:

```
foo(x); x.bar()
```

If I don't type anything then press Tab, I get:

```
foo(); bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to add the `:` in field 2:

```
DB_ID(${2})
```

Use field 2

```
${2/(.*)/$1${1:+.}/}
```

- capture all the typed text: `(.*)`
- replace it with all the typed text: `$1`
- followed by a `.` if the typed text is not empty: `${1:+.}`